# Name of trees but with possibly two parents for

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I was wondering whether there is a name for trees $\tau$ which could also represent coalesence as well as fragmentation in the following sense.
Either a node $v$ in $\tau$ has child nodes (possibly $0$) which are not child nodes of any other node (as in a normal tree), or $v$ has exactly one child node $u$ which is also the **only** child node of another vertex $w$ where $v$ and $w$ have identical distance from the root node.

The motivation for this comes from soft matter physics where two bubbles may fuse when they come "too close" or one big bubble may disintegrate into multiple ones due to instability or even disappear if it is two small.

One can establish that $\tau$ is a planar graph but aside from that I am not quite sure what can be said and, therefore, I was looking for literature but I am lacking a name.

Comment: As you have described the graph, it is not necessarily planar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that the shard child node is also the only one for $w$. But now I am having douts whether it is planar even in that case...

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this very specific type of graph, but it's an example of a directed acyclic graph (dag)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this graph?

If the edges can be said to be directed from parent node to child node, then you can say $\operatorname{indeg}(root) = 0$, for each non-root node $v$ and $1 \leq \operatorname{indeg}(v) \leq 2$.

Other constraints are necessary to capture

"$v$ has exactly one child node $u$ which is also the **only** child node of another vertex $w$ where $v$ and $w$ have identical distance from the root node."

Comment: The set of all these graphs (with labels to represents the size of each bubble) is the state space of some random process which does exactly what I mentioned in terms of coalescing and fragmenting bubbles. The indegree of a non-root node is either 1 or 2 and not equal to 2.

Comment: @Jfischer Take root $r$ and give it four children $a,b,c,d$. (This and later child steps can be split up into two stages if each node can only have two children.) Give $a$ four children $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ and the same for $b,c,d$. Now merge $a_1, b_1$ into $x_1$; merge $c_1, d_1$ into $y_1$; merge $x_1, y_1$ into $z_1$. Do the same to get $z_2, z_3, z_4$. The resulting graph has a $K_{4,4}$ minor with $\{a, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ through $\{d, d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4\}$ on one side and $\{x_1, y_1, z_1\}$ through $\{x_4, y_4, z_4\}$ on the other side.

Comment: "$1$ or $2$ and not equal to $2$?"

I think you can capture the other constraint as follows:

$\operatorname{indeg}(v) = 2 \implies (\forall p \in P(v): \operatorname{outdeg}(p) = 1) \land (\{p_1, p_2\} = P(v): \operatorname{depth}(p_1) = \operatorname{depth}(p_2)$ where $P(v)$ is the of the parents of $v$ and always satisfies $\lVert P(v) \rVert = \operatorname{indeg}(v)$.

Comment: @joseville Okay, but what's the point of writing the constraint in symbols, other than making it harder to read?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for the example, I do not see the minor yet but I will work it out!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Formalizing and locking down its defining properties make it more tenable. Its sometimes easier to work with symbolic definitions than phrases if you're trying to proof something about this type of graph. It also narrows down the scope.

Comment: @joseville Strong disagree, but this is not the place for a continued discussion.